# How can I capture Debug Logs for Web to Lead form?

Tags: web2lead, debug-logs, duplicate-matching-rule

The error is

Salesforce could not create this lead because of the reason listed below. For more information about this error or help with Web-to-Lead, please contact Customer Support.

Reason: Use one of these records?
Lead Capture Page: https://54574246-atari-embeds.googleusercontent.com/

Can I capture the error from Debug Logs if so How can I capture Debug Logs for Web to Lead form?

Comment: Likely due to [Duplicate Rules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management/sales_admin_duplicate_management_unit_2)

Answer (score 2):

"Use one of these records?" is a message from Salesforce duplicate rules.  This [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336839&mode=1&type=1) explains how to adjust your rules to allow web-to-lead to bypass them.

> For Web-to-Lead submissions, if a duplicate matching rule is set up to
> block, or allow with an alert, Web-to-Lead submissions that match the
> duplicate rule will always be blocked.
>
> To allow a duplicate Lead to be created through Web-to-Lead, consider:
>
> 1. Add a Condition on the existing Duplicate Rule such that it does not run when the current user is the default Web-to-Lead creator.
> 2. Create another Duplicate Rule that runs only when the current user is the default web to lead creator, and set that rule to allow and
>    report (without alert).